# How to install or upgrade g++ in CentOS 6?

Tags: linux, centos, g++

I have CentOS 6, and have installed g++ 4.4.7 with `yum install devtoolset-2`

However, I want to install g++ 4.8 or higher. How can I do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can download the rpm from here, but note that the package is for CentOS 7. http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/gcc-4.8.3-9.el7.x86_64.rpm

Did you check here https://superuser.com/questions/381160/how-to-install-gcc-4-7-x-4-8-x-on-centos?

That what worked for me:

```
wget http://people.centos.org/tru/devtools-2/devtools-2.repo -O /etc/yum.repos.d/devtools-2.repo

yum install devtoolset-2-gcc devtoolset-2-binutils

/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/bin/gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-15
```

Comment: edited the post, added note that the rpm is for CentOS 7.

Comment: thanks friend, worked

Comment: Stas, any thoughts on how to get this to also work for g++ and not just gcc?

Comment: For g++:

https://gist.github.com/giwa/b1fb1e44dc0a7d270881